# Possible bug with dropdown user menu

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I noticed a discrepancy with the way the pulldown menu (I don't know what it's officially called, the sub-window that appears when you mouse-over your name at the top) displays reputation changes, and the way the reputation summary diplays rep changes.

Screenshots:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

As you can see, the dropdown displays +25 for my answer to 'How to pan in Blender?' whereas the summary diplays +15.

I can see how this could be [status-bydesign](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) because the dropdown displays total earned for that post, and the summary displays the most recent changes. If so, I would like to submit a [feature-request](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) that they be made consistent; to avoid confusion.

Comment: Were these screenshots taken while both elements were visible at the same time, on the same page? It does look like they present scores differently for me, too.

Comment: Yes they were. There was an upvote and an accept, but they happened a few days apart, so they aren't in the 5 latest rep changes

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. The popup menu combines the reputation changes of the past several days (a week or so, not all time) for the same post, to only show each post once, while the reputation list separates them by only displaying them chronologically. You can see a date-separated variant on the reputation tab of your profile which is between these two, combining some, but not as much.

Comment: @DanielBeck then I have a [feature-request] that they be clarified (such as saying "latest rep changes by post" or "by date")